# Why was this answer locked and deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleting, specific-answer

The answer at https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/17086/64 has 19 upvotes and no downvotes, and yet was locked by [Community](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) then deleted.

I'm not pushing for the answer to be unlocked and undeleted.  I'm just curious to know why it was locked and deleted in the first place.

Comment: Not sure why. Perhaps it is due to the rejection of the migration?

Comment: @CharlesMorisset Yes, I think it was automatically deleted following the failed migration (otherwise, the deletion would explicitly appear in the moderators' timeline view)

Answer (score 5):

I undeleted the answer, as I couldn't find any good reason for it to be removed.

Comment: Thank you for the response.